# Powershell command to get Owner or drive in windows

Tags: python, powershell, winrm

I am a new bee to Powershell. I am trying to get owner and access for a NAS drive in windows. I tried with `get-acl` via python(using winrm) but somehow its failing saying the drive which am trying to work on is does not exist.

Example :

```
get-acl 'V:'
```

However when I try the same command for C: drive it works fine. For NAS it says -

> "Error">get-acl : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name \'V\' does
>   not exist

Someone knows any other alternative command?

This command works fine when i login to that remote machine and execute, however gives above error when I execute through python using `winrm`.

Comment: Please show us the full command you execute in python to run this.

Comment: Also show the output of `Get-PSDrive`.

Comment: I need to get details for NAS drive. Get-PSDrive gives all the drive details. I need to get details on NAS drive owner and permissions.